A Question about an Error concerned "use of \@writefile"
I am using LaTeX to write a paper, and here are the packages that I used before the main texts:
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage [autostyle, english = american]{csquotes}


\setlength{\parindent}{0em} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[margin=1.0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for "\mathbb" macro
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\F}{\mathbb{F}}

\newcommand{\abs}{\lvert}
\newcommand{\n}{\lVert}
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\mkern 1.5mu\overline{\mkern-1.5mu#1\mkern-1.5mu}\mkern 1.5mu}

\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\newcommand{\DDelta}{\mathit{\Delta}}
\renewcommand{\qed}{\hfill\blacksquare}
\renewcommand{\b}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\im}[2]{
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=#1 cm]{#2}
\end{center}
}

\title{A Question about the Product of the Slopes of Two Line Segements within a Conic Section}
\author{Yunxuan Zhang, Mike Sukava}
\date{Nov 07, 2024 started \\ Dec 04, 2024 1st edition}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

When I begin to typeset, it shows me an error like this:
Package csquotes Warning: Load 'inputenc' before 'csquotes' on input line 49.

(c:/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./conic.aux)
Runaway argument?
{\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1 
! File ended while scanning use of \@writefile.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.49 \begin{document}
                 
? 

I am confused by the error here and can someone help me explain why this error occur and how to fix it? Thanks!

welcome! the error involves the addition of section to the table of contents, but your code doesn't include any \section, so all we can say is that the error is caused by code you've not shown. but you are also missing a backslash at the beginning of your code.

Thanks! Does the error warning indicate which section or which line of the section where I made the mistake?

it is reading conic.aux and reports the line as l.49 at \begin{document}, but the error in your code is almost certainly later. the way to find it if you can't guess is to copy the document, comment half your copy and see if the error persists. if not, comment the other half. otherwise, delete the commented part. repeat until you isolate it. note that you probably need at least 2 runs to reproduce the error.

Also consider deleting all auxiliary files from the original compilation (.toc, .lof, .lot, .aux, ...) and retry the compilation.

your .aux  is corrupted delete it and re-run latex to regenerate it.
